# SQL Server error: Subquery Returns more than 1 Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query, but I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    d.Description,
    s.Version,
    d.UtiPrefix,
    d.UTI,
    d.PrimaryAC,
    s.ReportingObb,
    s.ReportingObb,
    d.LEI,
    d.LEI_Countp,
    d.LEI,
    s.ReportingDeleg,
    d.Curr,
    c.Trade_Party_Domicile,
    c.LEI_SGR,
    Price = (
        SELECT Price
        FROM Price p
        WHERE p.DATE = '2014-09-15 00:00:00.000'
        )
FROM 
    Derivatives AS d
INNER JOIN 
    Settings AS s ON d.LEI_SGR = s.LEI_SGR
INNER JOIN 
    Clients c ON d.LEI_SGR = c.LEI_SGR
WHERE 
    c.LEI_SGR = '8156008BA0ABD6B3AE15'
```

Comment: your sub query return more than one rows. any foreign key have in price then join that also in sub query

Comment: What is your question?   The error message is self-explanatory.

Comment: select the SINGLE appropriate price instead.

Comment: i simply want to show more than one records i already tried with all suggested solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your subquery `SELECT Price FROM Price p WHERE p.DATE = '2014-09-15 00:00:00.000'` is returning more than one row. Your `Price` table has more than one `price` for `2014-09-15`.

Updated: I see in a comment to another answer that you want to show ALL the prices for that date in the results. You will need to join the `price` table into your query. Not subquery the `price` table in your SELECT clause.

```
SELECT d.Description,
    s.Version,
    d.UtiPrefix,
    d.UTI,
    d.PrimaryAC,
    s.ReportingObb,
    s.ReportingObb,
    d.LEI,
    d.LEI_Countp,
    d.LEI,
    s.ReportingDeleg,
    d.Curr,
    c.Trade_Party_Domicile,
    c.LEI_SGR,
    p.Price
FROM Derivatives AS d
INNER JOIN Settings AS s
    ON d.LEI_SGR = s.LEI_SGR
INNER JOIN Clients c
    ON d.LEI_SGR = c.LEI_SGR
,price p

WHERE c.LEI_SGR = '8156008BA0ABD6B3AE15' and p.date = '2014-09-15 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: yes i know that but whats the solution any idea please

Comment: If there are multiple records in the price table for that date, then you need to decide which price record you want to select. max(price), avg(price), TOP 1 price, delete all the other prices in the table for that date. I can't tell you how to select the correct price.

Comment: I have added a SQL statement to my answer that will cross join price in to your query results giving you multiple records, one for each price on `2014-09-15`

Comment: JNevil i tried with your solution it works infect why i didn't thought like this way . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you, your subquery returns more than one result. You can fix it like that:

For MySQL:

```
SELECT Price
FROM Price p
WHERE p.DATE = '2014-09-15 00:00:00.000'
LIMIT 1
```

For T-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Price
FROM Price p
WHERE p.DATE = '2014-09-15 00:00:00.000'
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: i already tried with top(1) but infect i need to show all prices according that date so i cant select only 1

Comment: In this case your problem is not to fix the error but to fix your query in order to get the expected result

Answer (score 1):

You need to force the subquery from returning more than one row.

One way is to use `MAX()`:

```
...
Price = (
    SELECT MAX(Price)
    FROM Price p
    WHERE p.DATE = '2014-09-15 00:00:00.000'
    )
...
```

Other options:

- `AVG()`
- `MIN()`
- `TOP 1` / `LIMIT 1` (etc depending on database)